# CDI Injecting EJB (Stateless) from lib jar

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, javabeans, cdi

I'm having trouble injecting dao bean declared on a lib jar.
So I have a jar (mine) with a persistence context, entities and daos. Here is a dao example :

```
@Stateless
public class SomeDao {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  ...

}
```

Now I want to use this dao on my main application.

A jax-rs use case :

```
@Path("rs")
public class WebService{

  @Inject
  private SomeDao dao;

  @POST
  public Response doPost(){
    //dao is injected but nullpointer thrown on EntityManager
    dao.doSomething();
  }
  ...
}
```

There is a beans.xml in both project (under META-INF/ for lib, WEB-INF/ for the web application). like this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

------------- Edit ------------

I've just found out if I remove the @Stateless annotation and the producer it works. So the problem is in fact : how to inject with CDI an EJB declared on an lib jar.

Comment: "Since this dao bean is declared on a different jar I should create a provider in order to inject it" where have you read this? It's not true.

Comment: That depends on which CDI impl you're using. Because it's in a different jar, it's actually in a different Bean Descriptor Archive (BDA), to my knowledge, OpenWebBeans is the only CDI implementation which ignores BDA boundaries.

Comment: The implementation is weld.

Comment: @Adrian you're right big misunderstanding from me. Problem seems to because of the EJB annotation (@Stateless).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if this a jar you create and not a third party just, simply add a beans.xml in the correct location for the jar and you'll have those objects available for injection. That's the easiest way.

If it is a third part jar, your next best idea is to create a portable extension and listen to the `BeforeBeanDiscovery` in CDI 1.0 or `AfterTypeDiscovery` in CDI 1.1 and call the `addAnnotatedType` method to add in those classes you need from the jar. You'd create this extension in your war / ear classpath.

Comment: The jar is mine and it has a beans.xml under /META-INF.

Comment: war or ear deployment?

Comment: It's just a simple webservice for now so the final deployment is a war with the jar lib under /WEB-INF/lib